# How do I access a dotenv variable in a html file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, dotenv

I'm using NodeJS and Electron to make an app. As Electron uses HTML, I need  a `<script>` tag in my HTML page to access a `process.env` variable. Is this possible, and if so how? I've been searching Google for ages now, and I can't find an answer. Sorry if my question isn't very clear.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you have node integration in your html? If so just require `remote` module, then use [`remote.process`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#remoteprocess)

Comment: @pergy how would I integrate node?

Comment: Are you using a templating engine for the HTML?

Comment: @KevinPrasannaRR No, I'm creating it from scratch

Comment: How do you plan to access this env variable? Over a HTTP request? Or do you want it already loaded in the UI?

Comment: @KevinPrasannaRR My .env file is in my root folder, and my HTML file is in the src folder, which is in the root folder. My main.js is also in the root folder.

Comment: @PixelOrangeDev So your main.js or a different js file are the only ones that can have access to the env var using `process.env` as part of the backend. If it is an environment variable only for the front-end side of your app, have a look at this [link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3105)

Comment: @KevinPrasannaRR Thanks, but I managed to find a different way of achieving the same result I was going for. I'm new to electron, and was under the impression that you had to load from a html file, not a website, but you can. Thanks for the suggestions, anyway, they did help. 

Comment: Great. Sounds good